# ufw differentiates block-and-log from unmatched log

Tags: 18.04, iptables, ufw

I insert block rules using this kind of statements

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny log from 45.136.228.230/24
```

I have a few hundreds of such deny-log rules.

ufw will block the IP and log the event. However, another feature that comes with `ufw logging low` is that ufw will also log packets not matching the defined policy.

I want to separate or differentiate the ones I explicitly set as `deny log` from the ones because of unmatching.

`--log-prefix` in /etc/ufw/user.rules looks promising, but once I add new rules to ufw through the ufw interface, my modifications on user.rules are lost.

How do I set up so that for each entry in ufw.log, I can quickly tell if it's blocked by my deny-log rules or because of not matching the defined policy?